# GNU-Octave: load data which contains geometric lines as blocks of coordinates

Tags: matlab, load, line, octave

I would know if there is a way to load data stored like this in a file:

```
$ cat foo
12.108 24.21; 89.02 17.3131; 93.192368 13.10012; ....
10.3069 41.7442; 90.1277 19.351; 93.192368 13.10012; 91.1956 15.29712; ...
...
```

So the form is:
`x y; x y; x y;` and so on.
Each point defined by a couple of `x y` values is a point constituting a geometric line.

Each line of the file contains a unique geometric line which is defined by its sequence of points. Some lines are made of only two points, others of several. It varies. So as there is no constant number of fields I'm now unable to load that file.

Ideally, I'd like to store each line in a variable, or better, all **lines** in a kind of indexed structure, cell or nD-matrix so that I can further easily loop on their segments (a segment is defined by 2 **consecutive** points within a line).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Storing data in an array seems to be an elegant solution:

```
fid=fopen("File.csv");
tline=fgetl(fid);
ix=1;
while ischar(tline)
    A{ix}=str2num(tline);
    tline=fgetl(fid);
    ix=ix+1;
end
fclose(fid);
```

1. Open the file using `fopoen`
2. Use `fgetl` to initialize `tline` with
3. Set an iterative value, here `ix`, to 1 (avoiding `i` is a good idea as it is also a mathematical constant...)
4. While `tline` is a char (remember, at the end of file `fgetl` returns `-1`) store the `fgetl` returned line converted to a `num` value using `str2num` in the `A{ix}` part of the `A` array.
5. Don't forget to close the file with `fclose`.

Thus, `A{ix}` is taking the ix-th line of the input file in (x,y) structured sub-arrays:

```
> A{1}
ans =
   12.108        24.21
    89.02      17.3131
93.192368     13.10012
...


> class(A{1})
ans = double
```

---

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Line_002dOriented-Input.html